# Java jsoup post request 500 Quora login

Tags: java, jsoup, quora

We have tried tons of Java web utilities, and they are all returning 500 when we try to post to the Quora login URL. We used the Chrome networking tab to find the headers/request stuff and everything should be set perfectly. We are not sure why it is returning 500 server error every time we try to send a post request to login.

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36";

public static void test(String email, String password) throws IOException {

    // Login first
    String loginFormUrl = "https://quora.com/login";
    String loginActionUrl = "https://www.quora.com/webnode2/server_call_POST";

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).userAgent(USER_AGENT).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute(); // removed useragent

    // "formkey": "f3e47dd339ed5673c9411822ad5ff1da", length = 32
    String[] key = loginForm.body().split("formkey\": \"");
    String[] wat = key[1].split("\",");
    String formkey = wat[0];

    // windowId, length = 27
    String[] parts = loginForm.body().split("windowId = \"");
    String[] another = parts[1].split("\";");
    String windowId = another[0];

    // Vcon
    String[] vcon1 = loginForm.body().split(Pattern.quote("new(require(\"login\").LoggedOutHomeHeaderInlineLogin"));
    String[] vcon2 = vcon1[1].split("\",\"");
    vcon2[0] = vcon2[0].replace(")(\"", "");
    String vcon_json = "["+vcon2[0]+"]";

    // Cookies
    String result = "";
    boolean first = true;
    for(String c : loginForm.cookies().keySet()){
        String value = loginForm.cookies().get(c);
        if(first){
            result = result + c + "=" + value;
            first = false;
        }
        else{
            result = result + "; " + c + "=" + value;
        }
    }

    Connection.Response loginPage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
              .data("json", "{\"args\":[],\"kwargs\":{\"email\":\""+email+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\",\"passwordless\":0}}")
              .data("formkey", formkey)
              .data("window_id", windowId)
              .data("__vcon_json", vcon_json)
              .data("__vcon_method", "do_login")

              .header("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, **; q=0.01")
              .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
              .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
              .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
              .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
              .header("Content-Length", loginForm.body().length()+"")
              .header("Cookie", result)
              .header("Host", "www.quora.com")
              .header("Origin", "https://www.quora.com")
              .header("Referer", "https://www.quora.com/")
              .header("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
              .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")

              .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
              .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
              .followRedirects(true)
              .referrer("https://www.quora.com/")

              .method(Method.POST)
              .execute();

    System.out.println(loginPage.statusCode());
}
```